# Firestore rules difficulty

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following firestore setup, how can I set the rules to let only owners of marketCompra, marketTroca and marketVenda documents to delete?
The other ones I will let everybody see.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not have a built-in concept of a "document owner".  For that, your app will need to include data indicating which user "owns" the document (for example having a `ownerUid` field set to the Firebase Authentication UID of the user that created/owns the document) and then in your Firestore Rules you can ensure that the `allow delete:` condition checks the current `request.auth.uid` to that field's value.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /marketCompra/{docId} {
        allow delete: if isOwner();
    }

    function isOwner() {
        return request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.ownerUid;
    }
  }
}
```

For "The other ones I will let everybody see",  you can simply use:

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid != null
```

meaning that as long as the user is logged in to the app, they can issue a read request against this collection (or document).

By the way, you might find this article worthy of a review: https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-rules-recipes/